# How to dynamically upload data from Scrapinghub to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am running periodic spiders in Scrapy Cloud and exporting the results to an AWS S3 Bucket. I need to dynamically upload my Wordpress tables with these results and I am currently using TablePress plugin which has a "Import tables" option but it only allows me to update the tables each 15 minutes.

Is there any way I could perform these periodic updates every 5 minutes, or better, when the AWS S3 file changes?

A Wordpress plugin that works with Scrapinghub directly could solve my problem too, but I have searched and haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a JSON feed - https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-content-importer/

Answer (score 0):

From you Spider on ScrapingHub, you can either

1. Send each one of item from your Spider using [`item_scraped`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped) method
2. Send all items once your Spider finishes using [`spider_closed`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) method

Of course you will an API in your website to receive that data

Hope that helps

Comment: And how can I build an API in my Wordpress website to receive data and show it dynamically?

Comment: You can create a lambda (AWS Lambda) which will trigger everytime a new file is uploaded in the S3 Bucket (with the feed export), this lambda can ping your website at a specific url with the path of the file. e.g: mywebsite.com/import_from_s3/?path=myspider/myfile_20190328.json

Comment: @JorgeGarcia if you dont know how to create a simple API to receive data you should hire an actual programmer to do that